# Blazor .NET Core 3.0 - Can cshtml pages use MainLayout.razor

Tags: layout, blazor, .net-core-3.0

With previous versions of Blazor all files were cshtml pages and were able to use _layout similar to MVC projects - all was well.

But now in the new .NET Core 3.0 release Blazor template switched to *.razor files which are razor components (not razor pages). And the layout is now **Shared/MainLayout.razor** and is applied via routing in **App.razor** file:

```
<RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
```

So this creates confusion. We're still able to add razor pages (.cshtml files) to the project but they do not get the layout applied. It would be a pain to create and maintain 2 separate identical layouts, 1 for razor pages and 1 for razor components. I was unable to find any guidance for this.

Is there any way to apply razor component layout (**Shared/MainLayout.razor**) to razor pages (.cshtml files) inside the same project? Of if not, what is the recommended approach?

Comment: having similar issue as I have had to scaffold some identity in order to alter the login and other pages. There doesn't seem to be a way to inherit the layout as you stated. Did you ever find a way around this?

Comment: It appears this is still an issue in .net 7.  I scaffolded identity to customize login, etc. and it appears I'm going to have to maintain two layouts.  I'm going to look into replacing the identity razor page (.cshtml) into a razor component page (.razor).

Answer (score 2):

The quick answer is no. Currently you can load Razor Components into a Razor Page but can’t load a Razor Page in a Razor Component. This is stated in the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.0#integrate-components-into-razor-pages-and-mvc-apps).

I’m not sure there is a recommended approach as such - Except to try and refactor to Razor Components as much as possible, if using components everywhere is your goal.

If you want to keep a mix then I would suggest sticking with Razor Pages as pages (hope that makes sense) and only use components within those pages. That way you would only need the one Layout type.

Comment: Can the NotFound component (in App.razor) set the layout to a _Layout.cshtml?
The whole app is for authorized users only. I already have a .cshtml layout for the identity pages, can that be used or do I need to create yet a third layout?

Answer (score 2):

in the *head* of your _Layout page add

```
<base href="~/" />
```

in the bottom of *body*  add

```
<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
```

then in your
*_Host.cshtml*
file add

```
@{
    Layout = "_Layout"; //your Layout name
}
```

for more information follow this [link](https://mikaelkoskinen.net/post/combining-razor-blazor-pages-single-asp-net-core-3-application)

Answer (score 1):

I currently have the same problem and it's really annoying. Would also be interested in a solution for this. I can't even load the layout with

```
@{

    Layout = "shared/MainLayout.razor";
}
```

because it expects a file with the name **MainLayout.razor.cshtml** then.